# How to evaluate this integral $\int_0^\infty dx \; \log (1-\exp(-a x^2)) $ for $a>0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm stuck trying to workout this integral $$\int_0^\infty  dx \; \log (1-\exp(-a x^2)) $$ for $a>0$. So, I tried first to do Taylor Series of the integrand, that is $$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty  dx \; \log (1-\exp(-a x^2)) &= \int_0^\infty dx \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}(-\exp(-a x^2))^k}{k}\\
&= \sum_{k+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \int_0^\infty dx \exp(-akx^2)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2 (ak)^{1/2}}\\
&= \left( \frac{\pi}{4a} \right)^{1/2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{3/2}} \end{align} $$

This last series, clearly converges. I also tried to do something in the lines of using Leibniz rule for integration, but nothing promising yielded.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks  in advance.

Comment: [possibly related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one mistake! Here I lay my corrected computation 
$$\begin{align} \int_0^\infty  dx \; \log (1-\exp(-a x^2)) &= \int_0^\infty dx \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}(-\exp(-a x^2))^k}{k}\\
&= \sum_{k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \int_0^\infty dx \exp(-akx^2)= \left( \frac{\pi}{4a} \right)^{1/2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{3/2}} \\ &=\left( \frac{\pi}{4a} \right)^2 \zeta(3/2) \end{align} $$ 
Now it yields my expected result!

Comment: Shouldn't there be an overall $-$ sign? (The integrand $\ln(1-e^{-ax^2})=-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1ke^{-akx^2}$ is negative.)